# EventMachine Web-socket Client TLS Connections

Tags: ruby, ssl, websocket, eventmachine

I am having difficulty in getting EventMachine Web-socket client to connect to a secure web-socket server `wss://` using TLS.

I have an EventMachine web-socket server setup and running fine. I can use javascript from the browser and the connections work great. Just can't get the EventMachine Web-socket client connections to work.

I am thinking it might be something with the certificates but not sure how to tell.

Here is my client code:

```
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-websocket-client'

EM.run do
    conn = EventMachine::WebSocketClient.connect("ws://0.0.0.0:9110/message")

    conn.callback do
        data = {data: 'data'}
        conn.send_msg data.to_json
    end

    conn.errback do |e|
        puts "Got error: #{e}"
    end

    conn.stream do |msg|
        puts "<#{msg}>"
        conn.close_connection
    end

    conn.disconnect do
        puts "success"
        EM::stop_event_loop
    end
end
```

I get no error(s)? I can decipher from the client. And on the server (running in debug mode) shows only:

```
[[:initialize]]
[[:unbind, :connection]]
```

I have also tried replacing the ws:// with wss:// to no avail.

By the way everything works fine if I take encryption out of the problem.

Anyone else have success with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that currently `EventMachine::WebSocketClient` does NOT support `wss://` connections. The server does, but that is a separate project.

I ended up using [faye-websocket-ruby](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby) which does support `wss://`

There are examples in the README.md on how to use.